# Making new column by subtracting date column from current date after joining tables in SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena, presto, getdate

I have two tables that I have joined and I want to add to the result of that join another column. This column will be the result of the current date minus the column date called `start_date`. I would like to call the new column days because the difference would be in days.

Here is how my join looks like:

```
SELECT t.kind,
         t.start_date,
         t.user,
         t.user_email,
         t.completed,
         g.name
FROM d_trans AS t
JOIN d_gar AS g
    ON t.rest_id = g.id
WHERE t.completed = false
        AND t.kind = 'RESTING';
```

My SQL coding skills are limited. I usually just work with R after importing the data. This would be simple in R but I am not sure how to do this in SQL. I looked online for similar questions and I saw things like `ALTER TABLE ADD` to add a new column and the function `GETDATE()` to get the current date but everything I tried did not work. I am working in Athena from AWS I don't know if my problems are due to the limitations of Athena.

Comment: How precise does the result of the subtraction have to be?

Comment: Rounding is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date_diff('day', current_date, date_col) function:

```
SELECT   t.kind,
         t.start_date,
         t.user,
         t.user_email,
         t.completed,
         g.name,
         date_diff('day', cast(t.start_date as timestamp), current_timestamp)  as days
FROM d_trans AS t
JOIN d_gar AS g
    ON t.rest_id = g.id
WHERE t.completed = false
        AND t.kind = 'RESTING';
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. The output however is negative I assume if i just swap around the places of current_date and start_date it will be positive.

Comment: @Nick Yes, swap it and use current_timestamp instead of cast(current_date as timestamp)